# spring - bake in component resolution

Tags: java, spring

dependency injection might be good in theory - but in our world, it's just slow.  Whenever we run tests or start our application - spring is spending 50 seconds in various calls to the PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.

Is there any way to prevent that - to short circuit any spring discovery, and bake in a "when they ask for this bean, use this class" or something similar - so tat there is zero searching by spring?.

The main driver here is that creating a spring context takes literally 2 minutes - which of course is death to running unit tests by hand, where you want it to take more like 2ms.

Comment: It is not an issue with dependency injection particularly. It is more an issue with Spring and structure of your project. But to give you any more detailed suggestions how to improve it you would need to provide more information on your project, spring version, configuration, etc. I suppose you use component scan and autoconfiguration. Also as someone pointed out in your other question it might be an issue of mixing unit tests with integration tests.

Comment: The majority of your classes should have no Spring dependencies. Just create and wire up the objects as part of the unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your test-applicationContest.xml to initialize only required dependencies for your test. I believe when you are running JUnit test, you are testing part of your application and not a whole which in turn require to initialize few things. You can have multiple test-applicationContext.xml files for different JUnit classes.

JUnit with Spring provide handful Annotations to load specific applicationContext file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are referring to as unit tests are actually integration tests that require a Spring context and associated container creation.

For unit tests just mock out injected dependencies using something like EasyMock.

For integration tests consider testing only the appropriate slices of your tier to speed up testing. See here:

https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

Keep in mind that by using the Spring testing support you get a cached Spring context, so if you are writing integration tests, you generally only need to start the container once as Spring will cache it after that.